# Getting the last element of a level in a multiindex

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe in this format:

```
a   b   x
1   1   31
1   2   1
1   3   42
1   4   423
1   5   42
1   6   3
1   7   44
1   8   65437
1   9   73
2   1   5656
2   2   7
2   3   5
2   4   5
2   5   34
```

`a` and `b` are indexes, `x` is the value.

I want to get rows `1 9 73` and `2 5 34`, in other words, the last row of that level.

I've been messing with `.loc`, `.iloc`, and `.xs` for an hour, but I can't get it to work. How do I do this?

Comment: Is `a` always sorted?

Comment: @Divakar In my case, yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
print (df.groupby('a', as_index=False).last())
   a  b   x
0  1  9  73
1  2  5  34
```

If `a` and `b` are levels of [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.html), first call [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print (df.reset_index().groupby('a', as_index=False).last())
   a  b   x
0  1  9  73
1  2  5  34
```

Answer (score 4):

With `df` as the dataframe and the column `a` already being sorted, here's an approach -

```
df[np.append(np.diff(df['a'])>0,True)]
```

The basic idea is that we perform differentiation along the sorted column `a` and look for positive change with `(>0)`, giving us a boolean array. The `true` elements in the boolean array would signal the end of the "group" in that column. Since, there is no change for the last element of the last group, we need to append with a `True` element to that boolean array at the end. Finally, index `df` with such a boolean array to select rows off it and give us the desired output.

Another approach could be suggested with [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) using its optional argument `return_index` that would give us each group's first occurring element's index. So, to make it work for the last element, just flip the column `a`, use `np.unique` and get the first occurring indices and then subtract them from the total number of rows in `df`. Finally, index into `df` with those for the final output. Thus, the implementation would be -

```
df.iloc[df.shape[0] - np.unique(df['a'][::-1],return_index=True)[1] - 1]
```

Sample run -

```
>>> df
    a   b   x
0   1  26  46
1   1  17  32
2   1  12  65
3   1  31  96
4   1  34  10
5   1   7  80
6   1  64  50
7   1   0  34
8   1  93  28
9   2  18  92
10  2  59  22
11  2  87  31
>>> df[np.append(np.diff(df['a'])>0,True)]
    a   b   x
8   1  93  28
11  2  87  31
>>> df.iloc[df.shape[0] - np.unique(df['a'][::-1],return_index=True)[1] - 1]
    a   b   x
8   1  93  28
11  2  87  31
```

Comment: Using `np.diff` is a nice idea (+1) and can certainly be used for other problems, but I think it's a bit too complex for this.

Comment: `np.diff` just uses the sorted nature of `a`. So, less readable with a bit of performance to boast about it :)

Comment: Especially in cases where `groupby` would lead to a lot of groups (e.g. a lot of distinct values for `a`  and `b` alternating only between, say, 1 and 2), this approach will be much more performant.

Comment: If `a` and `b` are part of the index (a MultiIndex), and the index is unique and lexicographically sorted, and `b` always takes on consecutive values starting from `1`, one could use `diff` on `b` instead: `df[np.append(np.diff(df.index.get_level_values('b')) <= 0, True)]`. The boolean mask will be true when the corresponding element is greater or equal than the next (i.e. the diff is <= 0), meaning that it is the last row of the group (since the next row is "starting again" from 1).

Answer (score 2):

## Special case

The `groupby` solution presented by jezrael is the high-level, general solution. But when a `groupby` generates a lot of distinct groups (in the example presented by OP, that would be caused by a lot of distinct values for `a`), it performs quite poorly. Here I'm presenting an optimized solution for a special case (which matches OP's case).

Suppose you have a dataframe indexed by a `MultiIndex` with several levels, and the *last* of those levels has values that always start, within each group, at the same value; for instance suppose that the values always start from `1` and count up. In the following example this would be the `number` level.

```
                value
name number          
a    1       0.548126
b    1       0.774775
     2       0.483701
     3       0.820758
c    1       0.696832
     2       0.905071
d    1       0.750546
     2       0.761081
e    1       0.944682
     2       0.336210
```

Then, to get the cross section of the rows with maximum/last `number` value for every unique value of `name` (or combination of values of whatever other levels you have), you can do:

```py
df[np.roll(df.index.get_level_values('number') == 1, -1)]
```

and you get:

```
                value
name number          
a    1       0.548126
b    3       0.820758
c    2       0.905071
d    2       0.761081
e    2       0.336210
```

#### Explanation

Piece-by-piece:

- `df.index.get_level_values('number')`: gets an array of the values for the `number` level for each row
- `df.index.get_level_values('number') == 1`: boolean array that is `True` for those rows in which `number` is 1
- `np.roll(df.index.get_level_values('number') == 1, -1)`: shift all the values of the previous array backwards by one position in a circular manner (i.e. the first element becomes last, the second, first, and so on).

The idea is, the *last* value of a group will always come immediately before the *first* value of the group, which is always `1`. Therefore, if we get a boolean mask for the rows which have a `number` value of 1, we can just shift all of those booleans *backwards* by one, and we get a mask for the last values of `number`.

The special case of the last row is taken into account by shifting *circularly*, so that the first boolean ends up last—the first row always has `number` equal to `1`, thus that boolean will always be `True`, therefore the last row always gets selected (as expected).

#### Generic function

```py
def innermost_level_max(df, start_value=1, drop_level=False):
    assert df.index.is_lexsorted()
    level_values = df.index.get_level_values(-1)
    result = df[np.roll(level_values == start_value, -1)]
    if drop_level:
        result = result.droplevel(-1)
    return result
```

---

### Setup code to play around

```py
import itertools as itt

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import perfplot

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)


def generate_names():
    alphabet = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)]
    for length in itt.count(1):
        for tup in itt.product(*([alphabet]*length)):
            yield ''.join(tup)


def make_ragged_df(n):
    lengths = rng.integers(1, 3, endpoint=True, size=n)
    names = np.fromiter(
        itt.chain.from_iterable(itt.repeat(n, times=r) for n, r in zip(generate_names(), lengths)),
        dtype='U100',
        count=n
    )
    numbers = np.fromiter(itt.chain.from_iterable(map(range, lengths)), int, count=n) + 1
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([names, numbers], names=['name', 'number'])
    data = np.random.rand(n)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'value': data}, index=index)
    return df
```

This allows you to create a sample dataframe:

```
>>> make_ragged_df(10)
                value
name number          
a    1       0.548126
b    1       0.774775
     2       0.483701
     3       0.820758
c    1       0.696832
     2       0.905071
d    1       0.750546
     2       0.761081
e    1       0.944682
     2       0.336210
```

### Performance

Using `perfplot`:

```py
import perfplot

benchmarks = perfplot.bench(
    setup=lambda n: make_ragged_df(n),
    kernels=[
        lambda df: df.groupby('name', sort=False).tail(1),
        lambda df: df[np.roll(df.index.get_level_values('number') == 1, -1)],
    ],
    labels=["with groupby", "with np.roll on == 1"],
    n_range=range(50, 10000, 500),
    xlabel="total number of rows",
)

benchmarks.show()
```

[image: performance plot]

---

### Even more special case

If you know what the last value of `number` *always* is e.g. 3, you don't need anything more than an index slice:

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 3], :]
```

or a cross-section:

```
df.xs(3, level='number')
```

But probably if this is the case you wouldn't be reading this question to begin with.